# Overriding instance methods of a class by mixing in a module

Tags: ruby, module, overriding, mixins

Given a class A and a module B, mixin the instance methods of B so that it overrides the correspnding instance methods of A.

```
module B
  def method1
    "B\#method1"
  end

  def method2
    "B\#method2"
  end
end

class A
  def method1
    "A\#method1"
  end

  def method2
    "A\#method2"
  end

  # include B    does not override instance methods!
  #              (module gets mixed into the superclass)
end

puts A.new.method1   # want it to print out "B#method1"
puts A.new.method2   # want it to print out "B#method2"
```

Comment: Stipulation. You cannot explicitly swap the methods (e.g. you can't refer to 'method1' or 'method2' directly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove each of `B`'s methods from `A` before including `B`.

```
class A
  def method1
    "A\#method1"
  end

  def method2
    "A\#method2"
  end

  B.instance_methods(false).each { |method|
    remove_method(method) if instance_methods(false).include?(method)
  }
  include B
end
```

Or from within `B`:

```
module B
  def method1
    "B\#method1"
  end

  def method2
    "B\#method2"
  end

  def self.append_features(mod)
    instance_methods(false).each { |method|
      mod.send(:remove_method, method) if mod.instance_methods(false).include?(method)
    }
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but could not figure out how to do! Thanks!

Comment: An even better way to do it might be with the included(base) callback in the B class.

Comment: Updated the answer with another example to remove `A`'s methods from within `B`.

Answer (score 7):

[`Module#include`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Module%3ainclude) inserts the module `M` as a *superclass* of the class `C`. So, you can't override `C`'s methods in `M`, rather it's the other way around: `C`'s methods override `M`'s methods. (Technically speaking, Ruby doesn't make `M` a superclass of `C`, rather it creates an invisible *Include Class* `⟦M′⟧` whose method table and constant table point to `M`'s method table and constant table, and makes *that* class the superclass, but this distinction is not important for this particular question.)

In Ruby 2.0, there is a new method, [`Module#prepend`](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/trunk/class.c#L717-745) which, just as the name implies, *prepends* `M` to `C`'s ancestors, in other words, makes `M` a *subclass* of `C`.

So, in short: you can't, at least not yet.

Comment: Well, you *can* do it with some hacking (see Stefan's answer), but it is nice to know that Ruby is adding this, as it came in handy.

Comment: @JoeV: You asked about *overriding*, which (I assume) includes not breaking `super`. @Stefan's answer simply deletes the methods, there is no overriding going on, and thus, there is no way to delegate functionality to the superclass methods since *there are no superclass methods anymore*.

Comment: Now that we're well beyond 2.0, this should be the accepted answer IMO

Comment: for those in my position wondering what happens if you include module `M` in class `D` which inherits from class `C`
the answer is the methods in module `M` overwrite the methods in `C`, but as this answer points out, not the methods in `D`