# Overriding class method with a mixin

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have a 4-dimensional `NArray`, and I'm overriding `#each` so that it only iterates over a single dimension, then using `include Enumerable` for functionality like `#reject`, `#inject`, etc. However, `#sort` still iterates over every individual element rather than over the dimension I've selected.

Is there a way to explicitly use `Enumerable`'s `#sort` method, or do I have to write my own? I only have to call it once (so far), so it can be kind of weird or inconvenient.

**NOTE**: I realize that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057940/overriding-instance-methods-of-a-class-by-mixing-in-a-module) may seem like a duplicate. However, I do not want to ALWAYS override `#sort`, but rather just explicitly call `Enumerable`'s `#sort` method.

Comment: Give us the code you used, and the output you got, and what made you confused, and what you want, all details.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `sort` on the first level, whose elements are arrays, then `sort` will compare arrays. In order to compare arrays, the evaluation has to go inside those arrays, which means that it will be iterating over every level of array. It does not make sense to compare array elements while avoiding iterations into the sublevel. So if this is what you are trying to do, then there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

NArray has already `#sort` method and existing methods are not overridden through `include`. In Ruby 2.0, you can use `prepend` instead of `include`.